# Image Processing Terminology: Bit Depth

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, png, libpng

I'm doing some image processing, and I'm a bit confused by some of the terminology.  Particularly, I'm confused about the meaning of "bit depth".

I have a good understanding of the structure of a bitmap: it's basically an `M x N x channels` matrix.  So a RGB bitmap would be `M x N x 3`, and an RGBA (RGB with alpha-channel) would be a `M x N x 4` matrix.

However, there's another variable here, which is **BIT DEPTH** (or color depth).  According to the **[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)**, bit depth refers to **the number of bits per *pixel***.  So, an RGB bitmap would have a bit-depth of 24.

However, I've been playing around with `libpng` in C++, and `libpng` seems to define bit-depth as **the number of bits per *channel***, rather than per pixel.  So, an RGB bitmap can have a bit-depth of 8, meaning 1 byte (8-bits) per channel, and thus 24-bits per pixel.

Particularly, the libpng API function [**`png_get_bit_depth`**](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.get.bit.depth.1.html) returns `8` for a 24-bit RGB bitmap.  So, is the Wikipedia article using the terminology wrong?  Or is `libpng` wrong here?  Or is the terminology itself somewhat ambiguous?

Comment: Years ago there was something called High-Color graphics mode, having a bit depth of 16 bpp: 5 bit for the red and blue channels, and 6 bit for the green channel (since the human eye is more sensitive to green colour tones). I wonder what libpng would've reported in such a case when channel bit depth is not always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is wrong, though specifying pixel depth is by far more common. Generally the only time you'll see component depth is on stuff intended for experts. See also x264, which has 8-bit and 10-bit versions both referring to the component depth.